# Hangup notification sound

Tags: asterisk, pbx

**Background**

---

My client uses a Asterisk 1.6 based PBX telephone system as their call center solution. They use a soft phone application to pick up all calls from the inbound queue.

To reduce their work load, the soft phone application they use has a auto answer feature that the application can automatically pick up the call. To let the agent know there will be a call incoming, there is an Asterisk function called "Agent Announcement" that I can choose a custom prompt and play it before the call begins.

**Issue (Question)**

---

How can I program to play another custom prompt when the other party hangs up the call?

```
A (SIP Extension) <-> B (Customer)
```

If A hangs up the call first, there is no need to play a sound and notify B and it doesn't seems to be able to do that. But if B hangs up the call first, when Asterisk detected it, it should execute the hang up process. I want to play the custom prompt between the detection and the hang up process. Is it able to accomplish this? Thank you.

**What I have done**

---

I have tried to insert a `Playback` command above the line of `Hangup()` like:

```
[queue-688]
exten = 688,1,Answer()
exten = 688,n,Set(orgincallername=${CALLERID(name)})
exten = 688,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=${IF($[${ISDNISMATCHED} = 1]?${CALLERID(name)}:${CALLERID(name)}(TestQueue))})
exten = 688,n,NoOp(no set join announce)
exten = 688,n,Queue(queue-688,tTkKXx,,,30)
exten = 688,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=${orgincallername})
exten = 688,n,Playback(Beep) // This is where I put
exten = 688,n,Hangup
exten = fax,1,Goto(detect-fax-to-email,s,1)
```

But unfortunately, no Beep sound was heard.

Answer (score 2):

Please try c option for Queue app

c — continue in the dialplan if the callee hangs up (Asterisk 1.6.0 and above).

Something like this:

```
exten = 688,n,Queue(queue-688,tTkKXxc,,,30)
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Queue

Comment: The callee hears the Playback and being hanged up by the PBX. If SIP agent picked up and the callee hangs up the call, no playback. So ... the problem is still there but thanks for providing the solution!

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you might try: http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ACD_id288932.html

Check Using Local Channels part. 

The point is to have local channels as queue members, basically this means that all queue members will be just extension from dialplan and in this case in dialplan you can use Dial command. If you are able to use Dial command you can then check F and g flags of dial command, what shold allow to execute additional dialplan actions after hangup of caller or callee.